# Omniauth redirection working only in certain cases (with ports)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, omniauth

I'm setting up omniauth (just trying to get the facebook provider working for now).

I'm on my local computer running nginx on port `80`. I route all requests to port `8080` and run the default webrick server on `8080`.

I've set up omniauth pretty far, but now things only go smoothly in certain instances.

If my browser hits `http://localhost/auth/facebook` I get an error saying:

`URI::InvalidURIError, the scheme http does not accept registry part: app_server (or bad hostname?)`

If I hit however `http://localhost:8080/auth/facebook`, then facebook gives me an error message like `Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration."`. This makes sense since my site url is set to `http://localhost` not `http://localhost:8080`.

If I change the site url to `http://localhost:8080`, then things start to work (at least this far into the authorization process)

By the way, it's not just localhost by itself that is causing the problem. If I edit /etc/hosts and try something like `dev.example.com` it acts the same way, with `dev.example.com` not working and `dev.example.com:8080` working.

Why can't I get it to work with just `localhost`? Is it something wrong with the way nginx and webrick talk to each other? I can't imagine that'd be the problem, but it's the only difference I see in what works and what doesn't. Any ideas why the URI error is occuring?

Comment: did you find out? I'm passing the same situation now ;/ (I change my hosts and try to access http://example.com:3000/auth/facebook it is good but when I go to my website https://example.com/auth/facebook it raises the same error, is it related to http or https?

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the domain names for your facebook application. Go into https://developers.facebook.com/apps and edit the settings for that application. Set the site domain and app domains to whatever domain you want to allow redirection to (eg. example.dev)

Comment: I did that but it is still raising the same error, I comment my current situation down to the question.